# Variablising modal input

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I've been given a basic modal example that onclick opens up a specific html file in a modal window:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .hasModal,
        .inner {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .modal,
        .inner {
            position: absolute;
        }

        .modal {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: -1;
            transition: opacity .3s;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        }

        .inner {
            top: 10vh;
            bottom: 10vh;
            left: 50%;
            width: 80%;
            max-width: 960px;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 1em;
            transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
            transition: transform .3s;
        }

        .modal-content {
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 1em;
        }

        .close {
            position: absolute;
            top: 1em;
            right: 1em;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .show {
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .show .inner {
            transform: translate(-50%, 0);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="test.html" class="modalLink">click</a>

    <div class="modal">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="modal-content"></div>
            <div class="close" id="close">&#x2715;</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    var modal_html = '<h1>modal title</h1><p>modal content</p>';
    $(function() {
        var $body = $('body');
        $('.modalLink').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.modal-content').load(this.href, function() {
                $body.addClass('hasModal');
                $('.modal').addClass('show').on('click', function(e) {
                    if (e.target == this || e.target.id == 'close') {
                        $(this).removeClass('show');
                        $body.removeClass('hasModal');
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to adapt this to populate the modal window with a javascript variable object instead - e.g. `var modal_html` in the example.  Very grateful for any pointers.  Here's a [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/204L2hdk/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

```
$(function() {
  var $body = $('body');
  $('.modalLink').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.modal-content').html(modal_html);
    $body.addClass('hasModal');
    $('.modal').addClass('show').on('click', function(e) {
      if (e.target == this || e.target.id == 'close') {
        $(this).removeClass('show');
        $body.removeClass('hasModal');
      }
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks @thehuijb :)